# Moving lines startpoint and endpoints to coordinates

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I’m trying to make a script/function with the field calculator, or the modeller, or even the Python interface,  in order to move lines startpoints/endpoints over given points.
I have three layers:

1. GPS: point layer with ID field
2. Points: point layer with ID field, which matches the GPS one
3. Lines: line layer with ID_startpoint field and ID_endpoint field

[image: An exemple]

Points and lines are snapped together at startpoint and endpoint.
I managed to move points over GPS updating the geometry with the following formula:

```
geometry(get_feature('GPS','ID',"ID"))
```

How do I update the position of lines startpoint and endpoint too?

EDIT: the solution i want to obtain:[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not the full solution, but hopefully it gets you started.

What I did here was to split each line into nodes (vertices) then replace the first vertex with the geometry of the associated point, finally making a line from the new set of points.

Calculated on the line layer

```sql
with_variable('nodes', nodes_to_points($geometry),
    make_line(
            array_foreach(generate_series(1, num_points(@nodes)),
            
                case when @element = 1   -- when it is the first node of the line (start point)
                then                     -- swap the original node geometry for the associated point geometry
                    geometry(get_feature('points', 'fid', "fid"))  -- points is a point layer with a matching attribute field to the line layer
                else
                    point_n(@nodes, @element)  -- when it is not the first node, use the existing geometry (@points refers to the variable created in the first line, @element refers to the particular element in the array_foreach function (which is an array of integers from 1 to the number of vertices in the line)
                end
            )           
    )       
)
```

Blue dotted symbology is the original line, red solid line is snapped to its associated point.

[image]